# GA4+GTM+programmatic events

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have a website with several SPA-style pages or widgets. I currently use the Universal Analytics "ga" function to dynamically send events to Google Analytics, like so:

```
    ga(
      'MyLinker.send',
      'event',
      'Custom SPA',
      'Button Clicked',
    );
```

I've migrated to using Google Analytics 4 via Google Tag Manager with the GA4 Config tag.

How do I send programmatic custom events using my GTM and GA4 setup?

Comment: have you checked the docs.   https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/events?client_type=gtm

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo - that page tells me how to set up events within the GA4 interface. It doesn't tell me how to send programmatic, dynamic events though.

Comment: the code you have now doesn't use the measurement protocol either

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I ended up doing. Someone please correct me if I did extra work, or I did something incorrectly.

- GTM setup

  - Variables

    - GTM needs to know about the custom variables on the events.
    - I tried to mimic the old GA setup which hopefully will streamline things.
    - Variable names: event_action, event_category, event_label, event_value
  - Trigger

    - The GTM tag needs to trigger when events with a specific name happen.
    - type: Custom Event
    - event name: site_event
  - Tag

    - We need to set up a GTM tag which catches events with a specific name.
    - The GTM tag needs to grab the variables we give it in the event params.
    - configuration tag: (select the GA4 tag)
    - Triggering: (select the site_event trigger)
    - event name: site_event
    - Event Parameters

      - Parameter Name: event_category, etc.
      - Value: Select the variables for the corresponding values. They should look like {{event_category}}, etc.
  - Folder

    - I used a GTM folder to organize all these things into one place. This will hopefully make it clear that they are all associated with the task of tracking custom events.
- GA4 setup

  - GA4 won't show event params unless we tell it about them (I think).
  - GA4 > Admin > Property > Custom Definitions > Custom Dimensions.
  - Create dimensions for event_category, etc.

    - Scope: event
    - Dimension Name: event_category
    - Event Parameter: event_category
  - At some point I will need to create custom reports to make sense of my events and their parameters.
- Code

  - No additional setup is needed beyond the default GTM code.
  - To send a custom event to GA4 via the GTM tag, I used code like the following:

    ```
    dataLayer.push({
        event: 'site_event',
        event_category: 'Program Explorer',
        event_action: 'Course Popup Open',
        event_label: courseNumber,
    });
    ```
  - This could would happen when, e.g., a user clicks a button or otherwise interacts in a special way which we want to track.
  - You can leave parameters unspecified if they're not needed. For example, I've never used event_value.

Comment: I can't believe it's not working out of the box.
We have a lot of custom GA4 events fired by the code and they just stopped working after adding GTM and Google Tag. 
We wouldn't like to migrate all the events and redefine them in GTM.
Thanks for sharing your workaround